# JAVA: Design a service which let's clients override unique key generation logic

Tags: java, design-patterns, key

I am working on developing a service as a platform. This service stores record for different clients.
A client can have different fields which defines it's uniqueness.
Eg.
`employeeId` or
`employeeId + department` or
`employeeId + department + location`.

How can I design such usecase, which let's each new on-boarded client define uniqueness of their data and my service performs CRUD operation using those unique keys at runtime.

Thanks.

Comment: why do you mean by uniqueness? why can't the unique key work here?

Comment: My service has a datastore which is storing the values. So, for clientA data stored could be |employeeId|data| for clientB, same datastore can have entry like |employeeId+dept|data|

Comment: can't you use client_id as part of the key? @Alex